# use variables in Google Chart Options Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have created a Google Pie Chart using the following code:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
var options = {
  title: 'Meta Share',
      is3D: true,
      sliceVisibilityThreshold: .04,
      slices: {  6 : {offset: 0.2},
      },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I want to select a slice of the pie chart dynamically depending on what my user is doing. 
I now have the following code:

```
var slice = 8;
```

I would now like to use this variable in the above code, however; replacing the '6' with the variable 'slice' does not work.

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables as keys in object literals, you'd have to first create the object, then use brackets to use the variable as a key

```
var slice  = 8;
var slices = {};

slices[slice] = {offset: 0.2};

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
var options = {
    title  : 'Meta Share',
    is3D   : true,
    sliceVisibilityThreshold : .04,
    slices : slices
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Or with [calculated property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names): `var slice = 8, slices = { [slice]: { offset: 0.2 } }`

Comment: @Andreas - yeah, I love those, but they currently only work in Chrome and FF.